# Unable to import JDA into Maven - IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, discord-jda

I need to import [JDA](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA) dependency into my **Maven** (Java) project, yet IDEA doesn't seem to be able to import it for some reason. I did as following:

inside the *pom.xml* file:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.dv8tion/JDA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
        <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-alpha.11</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

*Main* class:

```
public class Main {

JDA bot = JDABuilder.createDefault("token");


public static void main(String[] args) {}

}
```

Importing doesn't work for some reason. I wrote this:

*import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;*

*import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;*

I tried various methods how to resolve this, like manually downloading source, javadoc, and jar files from the [website](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/dv8tion/JDA/5.0.0-alpha.11/) (not all of them though). Also I'm using **Maven 3**, if that could be a potential mistake.

I don't have much experience with Maven or importing dependencies overall, so I feel kind of lost at the moment. I've wanted to do the beginning of the code like in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFsxkWME7M0) I was following step by step up until this moment. Would appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

---

Edit:

I also tried running it on a different PC, still getting the same error though.

Comment: Try reloading the POM file. Intellij needs to be explicitly told when it changes so it will attempt to resolve the new dependency.

Comment: @Deadron I tried reloading it, as you suggested. Unfortunately it didn't work. Thanks anyway!

Comment: When it reloads you should see some log messages. If it can't find the dependency it should show an error.

Comment: @Deadron You're right, it shows 8 errors of Unresolved plugins. Example: Unresolved plugin: 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5'

Should I download all those plugins manually?

Comment: What is the output from `mvn clean compile` command in terminal for this project?

Comment: If it fails to download from the command line - there is an issue with network configuration on your machine. If you use VPN - try disabling it. If you use proxy - make sure it is configured for Maven.

Comment: @Andrey I ran the command, but the I recieved CommandNotFoundException. Also I'm trying this on a different PC now and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to have been my own error, that I didn't have a repository in the pom.xml file. All it took was to add it and it worked when I reloaded the file.

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.dv8tion/JDA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
        <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-alpha.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>dv8tion</id>
        <name>m2-dv8tion</name>
        <url>https://m2.dv8tion.net/releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

After pasting a dependency in pom.xml on right corner screen maven reload button will be shown press that button and check

Or

Try:
File -> Invalidate Caches... -> Check Clear file system cache and Local History also -> Press Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: Yeah the first method wasn't working because my rather stupid mistake, I didn't import repository into the pom.xml file. Although I did the first few steps by a tutorial, the guy in the video didn't add a repository and it worked for him just fine. Thanks for your advice though!